# How to pass object down into react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React newbie here! I have an object `cats` which contains a list of lat long cords for cat locations. I am trying to pass the object down into the MapContainer component like so:

```
<MapContainer cats={cats} /></div>
```

MapContainer component:

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cats: // this should come from the parent component
    }
  }

  displayMarkers = () => {
    return this.state.cats.map((cat, index) => {
      return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
       lat: cat.latitude,
       lng: cat.longitude
     }}
     onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")} />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={8}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}
        >
          {this.displayMarkers()}
        </Map>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I adjust my class component to take the cats object in?

Comment: did you try `this.props.cats.map` instead of `this.state.cats.map` in displayMarkers function?

Comment: props contains all properties that you set on the component

Comment: You'll need to use a lifecycle function to place the cats object from props into state, otherwise, as the other comments have pointed out the cats object is not present on state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks:

- You can access the properties passed to a child component through `props` in the constructor or `this.props` in other lifecycle functions
- It is considered [bad practice](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor) to copy the props value to the state.

So just access cats from props directly:

```
export class MapContainer extends Component {
  displayMarkers = () => {
    return this.props.cats.map((cat, index) => {
      return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
       lat: cat.latitude,
       lng: cat.longitude
     }}
     onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")} />
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Map
          google={this.props.google}
          zoom={8}
          style={mapStyles}
          initialCenter={{ lat: 47.444, lng: -122.176}}
        >
          {this.displayMarkers()}
        </Map>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally deriving state from props is not what you want. Why not use the prop directly? But if you really must do it like that (i.e. to initialize the state using the props that come in) you should check out the getDerivedStateFromProps lifecycle hook:

[getDerivedStateFromProps React.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

Comment: Thanks for this! I am using the props directly now and I feel like I just levelled up in React lol

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't need to convert the props `cats` into state in your MapContainer component, and instead just use the object / array as it is, but if you wanted to have it as state, you could do:

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      cats: props.cats
    }
  }
```